# Convert hours to minutes in an object array

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I want to figure out how to convert hours to minutes in an object array which has multiple movies in an array.

```js
let movies = [
    {
      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Frank Darabont",
      "duration": "2h 22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.3
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather",
      "year": 1972,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "2h 55min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.2
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
      "year": 1974,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "3h 22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9
    },
    {
      "title": "The Dark Knight",
      "year": 2008,
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "duration": "2h 32min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 9
    },
    {
      "title": "12 Angry Men",
      "year": 1957,
      "director": "Sidney Lumet",
      "duration": "1h 36min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.9
    },
    {
      "title": "Schindler\"s List",
      "year": 1993,
      "director": "Steven Spielberg",
      "duration": "3h 15min",
      "genre": [
        "Biography",
        "Drama",
        "History"
      ],
      "rate": 8.9
    },
    {
      "title": "Pulp Fiction",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
      "duration": "2h 34min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.9
    },
    {
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
      "year": 2003,
      "director": "Peter Jackson",
      "duration": "3h 21min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Fantasy"
      ],
      "rate": 8.9
    },
    {
      "title": "Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo",
      "year": 1966,
      "director": "Sergio Leone",
      "duration": "3h 2min",
      "genre": [
        "Western"
      ],
      "rate": 8.9
    },
    {
      "title": "Fight Club",
      "year": 1999,
      "director": "David Fincher",
      "duration": "2h 19min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.8
    },
    {
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
      "year": 2001,
      "director": "Peter Jackson",
      "duration": "2h 58min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Fantasy"
      ],
      "rate": 8.8
    },
    {
      "title": "Forrest Gump",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Robert Zemeckis",
      "duration": "2h 22min",
      "genre": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "Romance"
      ],
      "rate": 8.8
    },
    {
      "title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
      "year": 1980,
      "director": "Irvin Kershner",
      "duration": "2h 4min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Fantasy",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.8
    },
    {
      "title": "Inception",
      "year": 2010,
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "duration": "2h 28min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Sci-Fi",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.8
    },
    {
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
      "year": 2002,
      "director": "Peter Jackson",
      "duration": "2h 59min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Fantasy"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "One Flew Over the Cuckoo\"s Nest",
      "year": 1975,
      "director": "Milos Forman",
      "duration": "2h 13min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "Goodfellas",
      "year": 1990,
      "director": "Martin Scorsese",
      "duration": "2h 26min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "The Matrix",
      "year": 1999,
      "director": "Lana Wachowski",
      "duration": "2h 16min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "Shichinin no samurai",
      "year": 1954,
      "director": "Akira Kurosawa",
      "duration": "3h 27min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "Star Wars",
      "year": 1977,
      "director": "George Lucas",
      "duration": "2h 1min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Fantasy",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "Cidade de Deus",
      "year": 2002,
      "director": "Fernando Meirelles",
      "duration": "2h 10min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.7
    },
    {
      "title": "Se7en",
      "year": 1995,
      "director": "David Fincher",
      "duration": "2h 7min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "The Silence of the Lambs",
      "year": 1991,
      "director": "Jonathan Demme",
      "duration": "1h 58min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "It\"s a Wonderful Life",
      "year": 1946,
      "director": "Frank Capra",
      "duration": "2h 10min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Family",
        "Fantasy"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "La vita è bella",
      "year": 1997,
      "director": "Roberto Benigni",
      "duration": "1h 56min",
      "genre": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "The Usual Suspects",
      "year": 1995,
      "director": "Bryan Singer",
      "duration": "1h 46min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Léon",
      "year": 1988,
      "director": "Luc Besson",
      "duration": "1h 50min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Saving Private Ryan",
      "year": 1998,
      "director": "Steven Spielberg",
      "duration": "2h 49min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Sen to Chihiro no kamikakushi",
      "year": 2001,
      "director": "Hayao Miyazaki",
      "duration": "2h 5min",
      "genre": [
        "Animation",
        "Adventure",
        "Family",
        "Fantasy",
        "Mystery"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "American History X",
      "year": 1998,
      "director": "Tony Kaye",
      "duration": "1h 59min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "C\"era una volta il West",
      "year": 1968,
      "director": "Sergio Leone",
      "duration": "2h 44min",
      "genre": [
        "Western"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Interstellar",
      "year": 2014,
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "duration": "2h 49min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Psycho",
      "year": 1960,
      "director": "Alfred Hitchcock",
      "duration": "1h 49min",
      "genre": [
        "Horror",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "The Green Mile",
      "year": 1999,
      "director": "Frank Darabont",
      "duration": "3h 9min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Fantasy",
        "Mystery"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Casablanca",
      "year": 1942,
      "director": "Michael Curtiz",
      "duration": "1h 42min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Romance",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "City Lights",
      "year": 1931,
      "director": "Charles Chaplin",
      "duration": "1h 27min",
      "genre": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "Romance"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Intouchables",
      "year": 2011,
      "director": "Olivier Nakache",
      "duration": "1h 52min",
      "genre": [
        "Biography",
        "Comedy",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Modern Times",
      "year": 1936,
      "director": "Charles Chaplin",
      "duration": "1h 27min",
      "genre": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "Family",
        "Romance"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Raiders of the Lost Ark",
      "year": 1981,
      "director": "Steven Spielberg",
      "duration": "1h 55min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "The Pianist",
      "year": 2002,
      "director": "Roman Polanski",
      "duration": "2h 30min",
      "genre": [
        "Biography",
        "Drama",
        "Music",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "The Departed",
      "year": 2006,
      "director": "Martin Scorsese",
      "duration": "2h 31min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Rear Window",
      "year": 1954,
      "director": "Alfred Hitchcock",
      "duration": "1h 52min",
      "genre": [
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Terminator 2: Judgment Day",
      "year": 1991,
      "director": "James Cameron",
      "duration": "2h 17min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Sci-Fi",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Back to the Future",
      "year": 1985,
      "director": "Robert Zemeckis",
      "duration": "1h 56min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Comedy",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Whiplash",
      "year": 2014,
      "director": "Damien Chazelle",
      "duration": "1h 47min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Music"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Gladiator",
      "year": 2000,
      "director": "Ridley Scott",
      "duration": "2h 35min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "The Prestige",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "duration": "2h 10min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Mystery",
        "Sci-Fi",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "The Lion King",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Roger Allers",
      "duration": "1h 28min",
      "genre": [
        "Animation",
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Family",
        "Musical"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Memento",
      "year": 2000,
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "duration": "1h 53min",
      "genre": [
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Apocalypse Now",
      "year": 1979,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "2h 27min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Alien",
      "year": 1979,
      "director": "Ridley Scott",
      "duration": "1h 57min",
      "genre": [
        "Horror",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "The Great Dictator",
      "year": 1940,
      "director": "Charles Chaplin",
      "duration": "2h 5min",
      "genre": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Sunset Blvd.",
      "year": 1950,
      "director": "Billy Wilder",
      "duration": "1h 50min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Film-Noir"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
      "year": 1964,
      "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
      "duration": "1h 35min",
      "genre": [
        "Comedy"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Nuovo Cinema Paradiso",
      "year": 1988,
      "director": "Giuseppe Tornatore",
      "duration": "2h 35min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Das Leben der Anderen",
      "year": 2006,
      "director": "Florian Henckel von Donnersmarck",
      "duration": "2h 17min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Hotaru no haka",
      "year": 1988,
      "director": "Isao Takahata",
      "duration": "1h 29min",
      "genre": [
        "Animation",
        "Drama",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Blade Runner 2049",
      "year": 2017,
      "director": "Denis Villeneuve",
      "duration": "2h 44min",
      "genre": [
        "Mystery",
        "Sci-Fi",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.5
    },
    {
      "title": "Paths of Glory",
      "year": 1957,
      "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
      "duration": "1h 28min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Django Unchained",
      "year": 2012,
      "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
      "duration": "2h 45min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Western"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "The Shining",
      "year": 1980,
      "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
      "duration": "2h 26min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Horror"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "WALL·E",
      "year": 2008,
      "director": "Andrew Stanton",
      "duration": "1h 38min",
      "genre": [
        "Animation",
        "Adventure",
        "Family",
        "Sci-Fi"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "American Beauty",
      "year": 1999,
      "director": "Sam Mendes",
      "duration": "2h 2min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Romance"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "The Dark Knight Rises",
      "year": 2012,
      "director": "Christopher Nolan",
      "duration": "2h 44min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Mononoke-hime",
      "year": 1997,
      "director": "Hayao Miyazaki",
      "duration": "2h 14min",
      "genre": [
        "Animation",
        "Adventure",
        "Fantasy"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Oldeuboi",
      "year": 2003,
      "director": "Chan-wook Park",
      "duration": "2h",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Drama",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Aliens",
      "year": 1986,
      "director": "James Cameron",
      "duration": "2h 17min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Sci-Fi",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Witness for the Prosecution",
      "year": 1957,
      "director": "Billy Wilder",
      "duration": "1h 56min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Once Upon a Time in America",
      "year": 1984,
      "director": "Sergio Leone",
      "duration": "3h 49min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Das Boot",
      "year": 1981,
      "director": "Wolfgang Petersen",
      "duration": "2h 29min",
      "genre": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller",
        "War"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Citizen Kane",
      "year": 1941,
      "director": "Orson Welles",
      "duration": "1h 59min",
      "genre": [
        "Drama",
        "Mystery"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "Dangal",
      "year": 2016,
      "director": "Nitesh Tiwari",
      "duration": "2h 41min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Biography",
        "Drama",
        "Sport"
      ],
      "rate": 8.6
    },
    {
      "title": "Vertigo",
      "year": 2001,
      "director": "Alfred Hitchcock",
      "duration": "2h 8min",
      "genre": [
        "Mystery",
        "Romance",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    },
    {
      "title": "North by Northwest",
      "year": 1959,
      "director": "Alfred Hitchcock",
      "duration": "2h 16min",
      "genre": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "rate": 8.4
    }
]
```

Comment: *Especially* since you haven't asked a question about it, nor demonstrated *any* effort at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clone the data and return a new representation of `duration`, you can use a regular expression to match the hours and minutes. Once you have these two pieces of information, you can just multiply the hours by 60 and add the minutes.

Here is a breakdown of the regular expression I used:

```
/        BEGIN EXPRESSION
  (?:    BEGIN NON-MATCHING GROUP
    (\d) GROUP 1: HOURS (could add a '+')
    h    LITERAL CHAR SEQUENCE
  )      END NON-MATCHING GROUP
  ?      PRECEDING GROUP IS OPTIONAL
  (\d+)  GROUP 2: MINUTES
  min    LITERAL CHAR SEQUENCE
/        END EXPRESSION
```

```js
let films = [{
  "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
  "year": 1994,
  "director": "Frank Darabont",
  "duration": "2h 22min",
  "genre": [ "Crime", "Drama" ],
  "rate": 9.3
}, {
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "year": 1972,
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "duration": "2h 55min",
  "genre": [ "Crime", "Drama" ],
  "rate": 9.2
}];

const convertToMinutes = (timeStr) => {
  const [ , hours, mins ] = timeStr.match(/(?:(\d)h )?(\d+)min/)
    .map(v => parseInt(v, 10));
  return hours * 60 + mins;
}

const filmsWithNewDurations = films.map(film => ({
  ...film,
  duration: convertToMinutes(film.duration)
}));

console.log(filmsWithNewDurations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Very nice breakdown of the regular expression!
I now know much more about it!
Thank you!